# Visjs bar graph for time intervals instead of single timestamps

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Is there a way/workaround to build [visjs](http://visjs.org/graph2d_examples.html) bar graph for time intervals instead of single timestamps?

For example, I'd like to show bars for 10 minute intervals. The standard way to set data for a bar graph is in an array with single coordinates on X axis:

```
 var items = [
    {x: '2016-10-18 18:00:00', y: 10},
    {x: '2014-10-18 18:10:00', y: 8},
    {x: '2014-10-18 18:20:00', y: 9},
    {x: '2014-10-18 18:30:00', y: 5},
    ...
 ]
```

If in options we set right alignment and large bar width (for example 50 pixels) then under certain scale the graph is shown nicely - when a bar reaches the following timestamp, its width is shrinked without overlapping. Please note that actual bar width here is less than value set in options

```
var options = {
  style:'bar',
  barChart: {width:50, align:'right'},
  drawPoints: false
}
```

[image: graph with adjacent bars]

But if graph scale is changed, at some point bars will start covering not full intervals (10 minute intervals for this example). Because bar width set in options does not reach start of the following bar at this scale:

[image: graph with not adjacent bars]

I tried to set bar width in options to even larger value but at some point bars start overlapping:

[image: graph with overlapping bars]

Is there anything that can be done to improve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this can be achieved by adding 'end' property to the items (not sure if it was always there or was added recently). To get 10 minute intervals the items from the question should be configured like this:

```
 var items = [
    {x: '2016-10-18 18:00:00', end: '2016-10-18 18:10:00', y: 10},
    {x: '2014-10-18 18:10:00', end: '2014-10-18 18:20:00', y: 8},
    {x: '2014-10-18 18:20:00', end: '2014-10-18 18:30:00', y: 9},
    {x: '2014-10-18 18:30:00', end: '2014-10-18 18:40:00', y: 5},
    ...
 ]
```

When `end` property is used for the items, `width` property in the `options` is ignored.